# How to call my controller action when my button is inside the Json query inside the view page in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

My controller block is these:

```
public ActionResult delete(int id)
{

}
```

My Json code in view page is

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (data[i].ProductId && data[i].Name && data[i].ShortDescription && data[i].MediumImage && data[i].Price && data[i].IconImage) {                 
    var Photoq = "/Images/HomeImages/" + data[i].MediumImage;
    var Photo = "<img id='imgAd' src='"+ Photoq +"' width='100px' height='100px' alt='img'/>";
    txt += '<tr><td><div id ="result1" ><div>' + Photo + '</div> <div ><div>' + data[i].ProductId + "</br> Name- " + data[i].Name + "</br> Description " + data[i].ShortDescription + ", </br>" + data[i].Price+'<input id="Btnremove" type="submit" value="Remove" />' + "</br>";                            
  }
```

Last line i have my button with id="Btnremove"
My jquery code to call these is

```
function deletecart() {
  $("#Btnremove").click();
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("delete", "Home")')
};
```

But nothing is working to call the controller action...plz tell me the solution..And tell how to pass the some id through button click event.

Comment: Where are you calling `deletecart` from?

Comment: By clicking these button i want to go to controller action.I dont know how to go from here?

Comment: Looks like you need to remove `function deletecart()` and just bind to #btnremove click

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple products (I assume there will be, by seeing the for loop), then you will have multiple buttons in your page with same ID, which is not good for jQuery. I suggest, you use a class instead of ID.

In the posted code, I cannot find call of deletecart().

I would use a `document.ready` event in the main view to bind the click handler to the dynamic buttons

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('document').on('click', '.Btnremove', function(e) {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("delete", "Home")');
    });
});
```

Note that, I have added the 'click' handler to the document, not the button itself, this is because the buttons are created dynamically. Also, I have used class instead of Id.